# C# and ASP.NET Session casting error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET Web Forms page with an image control bound to an animated gif.  If I open it in Internet Explorer (as opposed to other browsers) and click a button on the page, which opens a file, the gif stops moving even after the file is opened and closed.  It won't start up again until I refresh the browser.  I'm trying to solve the problem with the following code:

```
protected void lnkStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  // Link Button Click Event
{
    imgRefresher.Enabled = 1 == 1; // setting Timer Control Enabled to 1
    Session["TimerEnabled"] = imgRefresher.Enabled; // storing 1 in Session
    Session["FileName"] = "myFile.exe";
}

protected void imgRefresher_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) // Timer Control Tick Event
{
    if (((int)Session["TimerEnabled"]) == 1) // This line gives me an invalid cast error
    {
        Session["TimerEnabled"] = 0 == 1;
        string fileName = Session["FileName"].ToString();

        // This part I stole off the internet and will actually open the file.
        System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(fileName);
        if (fileInfo.Exists)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileInfo.Name);
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileInfo.Length.ToString());
            Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            Response.WriteFile(fileInfo.FullName);
            Response.End();
        }
    }

    imgRefresher.Enabled = 0 == 1;
}
```

The line if (((byte)Session["TimerEnabled"] ^ 1) == 0) gives me an invalid cast error.  I've tried casting it into an integer, a byte, a char, a float, and a double.  The goal is to toggle Session["TimerEnabled"] from 1 to 0 so the next pass turns off the Timer Control.

Comment: imgRefresher.Enabled = 0 == 1; = Enablade Values is False... not an Integer

Comment: Isn't 0 the same as false?

Comment: jap.. But you cant cast an Bool to Int this way

Comment: imgRefresher.Enabled = 1 == 1 --> this will always evaluates to true, instead can't you simply use the actual boolean types (true or false), makes the code more readable and you dont have to cast

Comment: try with Parse: ``int.Parse(Session["TimerEnabled"])``

Comment: You guys are right.  It works now.  I looked up the C# boolean variable type online.  I assumed you just used 0 and 1.  I probably shouldn't make so many assumptions.  Anyhow, the GIF spins again now after the click and I learned about the boolean variable.  Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case it's better to use the type bool. (you cant cast bool to int like this `(int)myBool` -> invalid cast error

If you wanna us an integer you can cast like this:

```
int myInteger = (imgRefresher.Enabled) ? 1 : 0;
```

Change your Code to:

```
protected void lnkStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  // Link Button Click Event
{
    imgRefresher.Enabled = true; // setting Timer Control Enabled to 1
    Session["TimerEnabled"] = imgRefresher.Enabled; // storing 1 in Session
    Session["FileName"] = "myFile.exe";
}

protected void imgRefresher_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) // Timer Control Tick Event
{
    if (Session["TimerEnabled"]) // This line gives me an invalid cast error
    {
        Session["TimerEnabled"] = false;
        string fileName = Session["FileName"].ToString();

        // This part I stole off the internet and will actually open the file.
        System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(fileName);
        if (fileInfo.Exists)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileInfo.Name);
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileInfo.Length.ToString());
            Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            Response.WriteFile(fileInfo.FullName);
            Response.End();
        }
    }
    imgRefresher.Enabled = false;
}
```